# Insert text into text area by query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, nicedit

I am trying to insert some text into `<textarea>` by query but it is not working as I expect. I expect the colour code should get inserted into the `textarea` but `textarea` remains blank.

#### HTML code

```
<p id="niceedit">
    <script src="js/create/text_editor/nicEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
          new nicEditor({height : 100}).panelInstance('area5');
    });
    </script>

    <textarea id="area5" ></textarea>
</p>
```

#### Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.simple_color').simpleColor();
    $('input#alert_button').click( function() {
        var currentlySelectedColor = $('input.simple_color')[0].value;

        $('#area5').val(currentlySelectedColor);//HERE IS THE CODE

        $.post("defualt_templates/T1/Class_File/template_editor.php", { bgcolor: currentlySelectedColor },
            function(data) {
                refreshIFrame();
        });

    });

});
```

---

#### Question

What am I doing wrong?

---

#### Reference to external library

[NicEdit reference](http://nicedit.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#area5').text(currentlySelectedColor);
```

instead of this

```
$('#area5').val(currentlySelectedColor);
```

Or, there is a method inside NicEditor to find editor and then get or set the content.

reference : http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API

Comment: From Documentation : The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val() method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

Comment: Dillip bhai, NicEdit na documentation mathij solve thai gyu. Aema findEditor and pa6i setContent method use karine. btw Thanks